# How does the execution order of a SQL View work?

Tags: sql

Having an issue with text in a column that I need to be and integer. I filtered these values out with a view and hoped I could use the returned column as an INT.

The data:

[image]

The view definition:

```
 CREATE VIEW v_test as
SELECT [Id]
      ,CAST([InvoiceNumber] as INT) as [InvoiceNumber]
  FROM [Test]
  WHERE InvoiceNumber NOT LIKE '%ASD%'
```

The results when using the view:

[image]

Checkin the view in the tree, the column is an int.

[image]

I thought the view would return the top three rows, NOT the one with "asd" at all!
The view is obviously not executing first and returning only three rows back to me, that is THEN filtered with = 10. Eventually solved it with the TRY_CONVERT function, but **Can someone explain this !?**

Here is the exact same data if you want to test:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceNumber] [nvarchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([Id], [InvoiceNumber]) VALUES (1, N'10')
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([Id], [InvoiceNumber]) VALUES (2, N'11')
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([Id], [InvoiceNumber]) VALUES (3, N'12')
INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([Id], [InvoiceNumber]) VALUES (4, N'ASD')
```

Comment: There is a logical execution order to the whole query (the view is expanded into the query that consumes it and doesn't have any independent processing); The logical execution order says that WHERE occurs before SELECT. However, MS have resolutely failed to address [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/d54d50d8-6f25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0) for (checks calendar) over 12 years now. So due to optimizations, certain expressions may be evaluated before the "logical" order says they should and there's little to prevent it.

Comment: *The view is obviously not executing first* - that is correct, that's not how views (or any table expressions) work in sql server (that's not the case in some other dbms). The optimiser consumes the entire query text and can evaluate the expressions however it sees fit; use `try_cast/convert` on the expression. you can force the optimizer by using a *row goal*. Ultimately, if you expect it to be a number, store it as a number!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be enough to answer this with some copy from the comment section;

Thanks @stu

> The optimiser consumes the entire query text and can evaluate the expressions however it sees fit.

Thanks @damien-the-unbeliever

> So due to optimizations, certain expressions may be evaluated before
> the "logical" order says they should and there's little to prevent it

If I change "Where Like" in the view to:

```
CREATE VIEW v_test2 as
SELECT [Id]
      ,CAST([InvoiceNumber] as INT) as [InvoiceNumber]
  FROM [Test]
  WHERE InvoiceNumber <> 'ASD'
```

It works as expected.. :)

[image]

Comment: Note this is *not* a solution - it may not work at some point in the future perhaps when the statistics for the table update or when the data cardinality changes enough that a different execution plan leads to it changing where the expression is evaluated.